# Can the USW-Enterprise-48-PoE-EU be used in Britain?

Tags: switch, unifi, power-over-ethernet

I need to purchase a USW-Enterprise-48-PoE as our infra,

- is already Unifi based.
- needs all 48 PoE ports.
- is short on rack space.

| [image: USW-Enterprise-48-PoE] |
| --- |
| *USW-Enterprise-48-PoE* |

As the [USW-Enterprise-48-PoE-UK](https://eu.store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-routing-switching/products/switch-enterprise-48-poe?variant=41572014096566) is currently sold out, is there anything stopping me from getting a [USW-Enterprise-48-PoE-EU](https://eu.store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-routing-switching/products/switch-enterprise-48-poe?variant=41572014063798) and powering it with a standard UK C13 cable? I cannot see any other difference between the two models.

| [image: UK Plug to IEC C13] |
| --- |
| *UK Plug to IEC C13* |

Also asked on [UI forums](https://community.ui.com/questions/Can-the-USW-Enterprise-48-PoE-EU-be-used-in-Britain/e216ea6c-c4dd-4180-8a0c-505c51b8b1da) but no response.

Answer (score 3):

> Can the USW-Enterprise-48-PoE-EU be used in Britain?

Yes, the datasheet says "Universal AC input, 100-240VAC, 10A Max, 50/60 Hz".

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted Ubiquiti support who advised that,

> Yes, you can use the EU model in Britain. I checked the datasheet, there is only a plug difference, other parameters are same.